# Find elements that have non defined value in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, browser, jquery-selectors

I need to make a query in jquery which select elements with value=="". I works in IE but doesnt in chrome. I think that chrome had another value as non defined value.

My query:

```
var images = $('#images>div>input[type=file][value=""]');
if(images.length > 0) // ...
```

As you can see there are an input elements of type file which give user an opportunity to attach images.

```
<div id="files">
<div><input type="file" name="files" /><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeImage(this)" /></div>
<div><input type="file" name="files" /><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeImage(this)" /></div>
<div><input type="file" name="files" /><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeImage(this)" /></div>
</div>
```

In IE it works great but in chrome It always returns 0 elements.

Do you have any solution which can works on every browsers?

Comment: Can you post the markup (the HTML)? (Also, what versions of IE have you tried?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merge yours both answers and at last I wrote this:

```
var images = $(':input[type="file"]').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).val()==this.defaultValue; 
});
```

This works great. Thanks.

Comment: Nice work. You could always swap `:input[type="file"]` with [`:file`](http://api.jquery.com/file-selector/) too :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
$('#show').click(function(){
    $(':input[type="file"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == this.defaultValue)
        {
            $(this).css('border','2px solid red');
        }
    });
});
```

Instead of trying to compare the contents with a variable empty string or 'fakepath', etc, just compare it with its own `defaultValue` and you'll know if it has been populated or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/5sK7T/

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var images = $('#images > div > :file')
              .filter(function() { return $(this).val().length; });
```

Chrome, Firefox & IE definitely can get the `value` (though Chrome will only tell you the filename with `C:\fakepath\` prepended).

[What does your browser say?](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/hTvGQ/)